# enable active/current state on forum menu/nav

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

The current issue at hand is enabling a current/active state on a forum menu..Enabling an active/current state on a forum with just css wont do the trick...My basic understanding of this is...create a php ,jquery script that pulls the page id...and nail it down with jquery..which i'm not sure how to do..any ideas?

using phpbb3 forum template

**CSS**

```
#underlinemenu{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height:80px;
            font-size:14px;
            background-color:#f6f6f6;


            }

            #underlinemenu ul{
            margin: 0;
            margin-bottom: 1em;
            padding-left: 0;
            float: right;
            font-weight: bold;
            width: 100%;

            }

            * html #underlinemenu ul{ /*IE only rule. Delete extra margin-bottom*/
            margin-bottom: 0;

            }

            #underlinemenu ul li{
            display: inline;

            }


            #underlinemenu ul li a{
            float: right;
            color: gray;

            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 38px 13px 24px 13px;

            text-decoration: none;
            background: #f6f6f6 url(images/menudivide.png) top right repeat-y;
            background: #f6f6f6 url(images/menudivide.png) top left repeat-y;
            }
            #underlinemenu ul orphan item bullet a{
            color: black;
            background-color: #F3F3F3;
            border-top: 4px solid black;
            padding-top: 34px;
            }

            #underlinemenu ul li a:hover{
            color: black;
            background-color:#f6f6f6;
            border-top: 4px solid black;
            padding-top: 34px;

            }
```

**DIV**

```
<div id="floatMENU"><div id="underlinemenu">
                        <!-- IF S_ALLOW_JMENU -->



                                                  <ul>
            <li{U_INDEX_STYLE}><a class="orphan item bullet" href="{U_INDEX}" accesskey="h"><span>{L_INDEX}</span></a></li>



                            <li{U_PROFILE_STYLE}><a class="orphan item bullet" href="{U_PROFILE}" title="{L_PROFILE}" accesskey="u"><span>{L_PROFILE}</span></a></li>
            <!-- IF S_DISPLAY_PM --><li{U_PRIVATEMSGS_STYLE}><a class="orphan item bullet" href="{U_PRIVATEMSGS}"><span>{PRIVATE_MESSAGE_INFO}</span></a></li><!-- ENDIF -->
            <!-- ENDIF -->  


            <li{U_FAQ_STYLE}><a class="orphan item bullet" href="{U_FAQ}" title="{L_FAQ_EXPLAIN}"><span>{L_FAQ}</span></a></li>
                            <!-- IF not S_IS_BOT -->
                                                    <!-- IF not S_USER_LOGGED_IN --><li{U_REGISTER_STYLE}><a class="orphan item bullet" href="{U_REGISTER}"><span>{L_REGISTER}</span></a></li><!-- ENDIF -->
                                <li{U_LOGIN_LOGOUT_STYLE}><a class="orphan item bullet" href="{U_LOGIN_LOGOUT}" title="{L_LOGIN_LOGOUT}" accesskey="l"><span>{L_LOGIN_LOGOUT}</span></a></li>
                            <!-- ENDIF -->

            </ul>

                    </div></div>

enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved by using this code

```
 <li<!-- IF SCRIPT_NAME eq 'faq' -->  id="current1" <!-- ENDIF -->><a class="orphan item     bullet" href="{U_FAQ}" title="{L_FAQ_EXPLAIN}"><span>{L_FAQ}</span></a></li>
```

Comment: current 1 being the  id for the selected state in the CSS